# Why factorizing when determining limit of a function?

Tags: limits

I want to check if the limit of $f: \mathbb{R}\backslash\{−2, 2\} \to \mathbb{R}$ $$f (x) = \frac{1}{4 − x^2}$$ exists in $x_0=2$. A hint says that we have a fraction with a zero of the denominator as the critical point (ok, since $1\neq0$ and $4-2^2=0$), so we need to factorize the denominator. But why do we need to factorize $4-x^2=(2-x)(2+x)$? What's the benefit?

Comment: No benefit. Silly hint if it was specifically for that example. Conclude directly ($1/0^\pm=\pm\infty$). More precisely: as $x\to2^\pm,$ $4-x^2\to0^\mp$ hence $f(x)\to\mp\infty.$

Comment: Well, the point of writing $4-x^2=(2-x)(2+x)$ is to identify the root at $2$.  If you have spotted that directly (easy enough), there is no need to factor.  For more complicated quadratics, factoring could be a help.

Comment: Factorizing can be useful for considering uncertanties like $0/0$. For example $f(x)=\frac{x^3-8}{4-x^2}$ has limit at $x\to 2$ which can be found by factorizing numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is that factoring helps you to decide whether the answer will be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

$2+x$ has no role. But $2-x$ has.

If we approach $2$ from right hand side then $2-x$ will be negative or the answer will be $-\infty$

If we approach $2$ from left hand side then $2-x$ will be positive or the answer will be $+\infty$

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense... Thank you!